# Prove that $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} dz = 2\pi i f(z_0)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is Exercise VI.8.3. in Sarason's complex analysis.

> Let the complex-valued function $f$ be defined and continuous in the disk $|z - z_0| < R$. For $0 < r < R$, let $C_r$ denote the circle $|z - z_0| = r$, with counterclockise orientation. Prove that $$ \lim_{r\to 0} \int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} dz = 2\pi i f(z_0).$$

My attempt is to parameterize the circle $C_r$ by $\gamma(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$. Then 
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0 + r e^{it})}{re^{it}}r i e^{it} dt = i\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0 + re^{it}) dt.$$

Is
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} i\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0 + re^{it}) dt = i\int_0^{2\pi} \lim_{r\to 0}f(z_0 + re^{it}) dt?
$$

I do not know why it would be valid to interchange the limit and integral sign here.

If it is valid, I would like to use the continuity of $f$ to conclude that $i\int_0^{2\pi} \lim_{r\to 0}f(z_0 + re^{it}) dt = i\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0) dt = 2\pi i f(z_0)$.

Any help on why we can intechange the integral and limit, or suggestions on how to otherwise solve the problem?

Comment: You are missing a couple of integral signs  making the satements very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $f$ is continuous in the disk 
$$
\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-z_0| < R \right\},
$$
it will be bounded by some constant $M > 0$ in the compact disk $$\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-z_0| \leq \frac{R}{2}\right\}.$$ Thus, for all $r > 0$ sufficiently small, we will have
\begin{align*}
|f(z_0 + re^{it})| \leq M
\end{align*}
uniformly in $t \in [0,2\pi]$. Again using the continuity of $f$, it is clear that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{r \searrow 0} f(z_0 + re^{it}) = f(z_0)
\end{align*}
for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$. Thus, you can pass the limit into the integral by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I thought the dominated convergence theorem is for Lebesgue integrals not line integrals.